# Cannot set Finder window background colour / image

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I have created a folder inside HD>Users>Username (the folder where default things like Pictures, Movies, Sites, Documents etc. are) and I'd like to change the background image. The only thing is, the option is greyed-out in View Options.

Some info -

2009 MacBook Pro, Yosemite 10.10.4

[Seemingly] every other folder (including all default folders) (I haven't tested EVERY folder, obviously) can be changed.

I haven't changed anything in the folder's preferences etc. The only thing different is that a folder within this folder has a custom folder icon image.

The folders within this folder also cannot have their BGs changed.

I have tried restarting computer & relaunching Finder, to no avail.

Have I changed an option somewhere without realising? I have looked all over but no one seems to have had the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I just found a work around instead of a solution..

Made a new folder, changed background image and dragged everything over..

Thanks for the suggestion, I'm sure it would have worked but it seemed like a lot to try just to change the background on a folder.. A pretty pointless thing anyway really!

Comment: You should run my three suggestions anyway. Your issue implies deeper problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the standard toolkit first...

- In Disk Utility, "Verify Disk Permissions" and if necessary "Fix Disk Permissions".  Also "Verify Disk" and if necessary "Repair Disk".
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Update to 10.10.5 using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store